# How to avoid default URL encoding in ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers like RouteLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, html-helper, urlencode, cjk

I want my url like this:

"http://domain.com/tag/高兴"

My route mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute("Tag", "tag/{name}", new { controller = "Tag", action="Index" });
```

But Html.RouteLink will encode the parameters as default. If I use Html.RouteLink in my View, the generated html is:

```
<a href="/tag/%E9%AB%98%E5%85%B4">高兴</a>
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed my example.

This works in my case

```
<%= HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Html.RouteLink("Test", new { id = "高兴" }).ToString())%>
```

Make sure to change from <%: to <%=

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't generate URL without encoding.